# How can I modify/delete folders in Shotwell's sidebar?

Tags: shotwell

Shotwell has a "Folders" section in the sidebar (in addition to Events and Tags), and for me it contains multiple subdirectories, but one of these subdirectories is empty. How can I delete it? More generally, how can I modify this Folders section of the sidebar? Right-clicking does not do anything.

Here is an image showing the Folders section of the sidebar:

[image: Image of sidebar showing Folders section]

Answer (score 1):

Those folders are real folders on your hard drive.

By default, your Shotwell folder is just `~/Pictures`.

Open Nautilus (the file manager), and navigate to it. You will see the parent folder (e.g. `2012`, then go to the empty folder, e.g. `December`) and then you can delete it.

Click for bigger image.

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: It looks like you're referring to folders underneath the Events section; I am aware of the correspondence between the Events descendants and the filesystem structure. I'm not talking about that; there is a separate section, a sibling of Events, called "Folders", and that's what I'm asking about.

Comment: Those are the same, they are real folders. You can use them to import from anywhere

Comment: Tim, thanks, I do realize that they correspond to real folders, but the other folders in the Folders section of the sidebar disappeared once I removed their images from my library. There is a descendant of Folders for me that contains zero images, but it's still present under Folders. I'd like to know why it's showing up and how I can delete it from Shotwell (without deleting it on the filesystem).

Comment: Try adding a photo to it (on the file system) then drag that photo to the bin (in Shotwell).

Comment: Tim, I tried it, and it didn't work. When I dragged it to the folder in Shotwell, it imported it as normal into its own Event folder, but it didn't show up in the Folders folder...

Comment: Hmm strange. I'm not sure, sorry.

Comment: I backed up my photo.db file, and then, using sqlite3, deleted the three entries in PhotoTable whose filename value matched that folder. I restarted Shotwell and that folder was gone. If I can provide you those three records from my photo.db file, will that give you enough info to know why this was happening? I'm considering filing a Shotwell bug for this, but I need to confirm with someone that it's actually a bug...

Comment: I'm not that knowledgable to know. However, paste them to http://paste.ubuntu.com and post the link here ([edit] it in).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/22190/discussion-between-bluebomber-and-tim).